# JPA Abstract Inheritance with List<AbstractClass>

Tags: java, jpa, generics, inheritance

My code:

```java
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class Header {
    public abstract List<Line> getLines();
}

@Entity
public class ChildHeader extends Header{
    @OneToMany
    public List<ChildLine> getLines();
}
 
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class Line {
    public abstract Header getHeader();
}

@Entity
public class ChildLine extends Line {
    @ManyToOne
    public ChildHeader getHeader();
}
```

Problem: I get the error message "Error: '`getLines()`' in '`ChildHeader`' clashes with '`getLines()`' in '`Header`'; attempting to use incompatible return type"

Attempted solution: Change `List<Line>` to `<T extends Line> List<T>` and `List<ChildLine>` to `<T extends ChildLine> List<T>`

New Error: '`getLines()`' in '`ChildHeader`' clashes with '`getLines()`' in '`Header`'; both methods have same erasure, yet neither overrides the other

Attempted solution: Tried using `Line[]` and `ChildLine[]` instead of lists

New Error: "List/array has to be annotated with an `@OrderColumn` (or `@IndexColumn`)", but there is no ordering column. The order of the array doesn't matter, but seems like `@OneToMany` or JPA is requiring one.

This is an impossible situation. What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since *ChildHeader's* "getLines" isn't overriding *Header's* declaration (which, given it's an abstract method, will eventually have to be done), for all intents and purposes, you're attempting to overload the method by different return types.

In Java, that's not allowed.

Is there any reason you can't just override *Header's* "getLines" method like so:

```
@Entity
public class ChildHeader extends Header{
    @OneToMany
    public List<Line> getLines(); 
          // since this isn't an abstract class, there
          // should be an implementation here
}
```

Since "ChildLine" extends "Line", you could still return a list that has nothing but "ChildLine's". You'll just need to ensure that when such a method is called, those "ChildLines" from the *Line* list are transferred to a *ChildLine* List.

Similar logic applies to the line class. *ChildLine* is attempting to overload "getHeader()" from *Line* when it would be easier to override the method by making sure their return types match.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, it does seem like I may end up just having to do as you say with casting then `Line`s to `ChildLine`s when I need to use any `ChildLine` members. Thanks for the explanation, I guess I assumed that the Java compiler would be smart enough to recognize that because `ChildLine` extends `Line`, the `ChildHeader`'s `getLines()` is an override, not an overload.

Answer (score 1):

> „*…This is an impossible situation…*“

Not if you follow [*the JLS'*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.8.1-100-C) guidance on overriding instance methods…

> #### *8.4.8.1. Overriding (by Instance Methods)*
>
> *An instance method `m`<sub>`C`</sub> declared in or inherited by class `C`, **overrides from `C`** another method `m`<sub>`A`</sub> declared in class `A`, iff all of the following are true:*
>
> …
>
> - *The signature of `m`<sub>`C`</sub> is a subsignature ([*§8.4.2*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.2)) of the signature of `m`<sub>`A`</sub>*.
>
> …

Pay particular attention to [*the section on method signatures*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.2)…

> #### *8.4.2. Method Signature*
>
> *Two methods or constructors, `M` and `N`, have the **same signature** if they have the same name, **the same type parameters** (if any) ([*§8.4.4*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.4)), and, after adapting the formal parameter types of `N` to the the type parameters of `M`, the same formal parameter types*…

The crux of the errors you got is because your methods don't meet the JLS's criteria.

> „*…What can I do?…*“

If you refactored your *`Header`* class…

```
public abstract class Header {
    
    public abstract < L extends Line > List< L > getLines( );
}
```

And if you refactored your *`ChildHeader`* class…

```
public class ChildHeader extends Header {
    
    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public < C extends Line > List< C > getLines(){ … }
}
```

Then you could do [*what I demonstrate in this working example*](https://jdoodle.com/ia/X6)…

```
…
Header header = new ChildHeader( );
  
List< ChildLine > lines = header.getLines( );
  
ChildHeader childHeader = lines.get( 0 ).getHeader( );
…
```

Comment: Thank you. Seems like this is what I will need to do as I will effectively just need to cast my `Line` to `ChildLine` whenever they are `ChildLine`, as you are doing here. 

What I don't understand is why don't the methods have the same signature? A `ChildLine` is a `Line`, so therefore `List<ChildLine>` is a `List<Line>`. We see this for the `getHeader()` methods where the overriding works as expected.

Comment: If for some reason the `List` generics cannot use inheritance, I still don't understand, because in my example I mentioned that I tried changing `List<ChildLine>` to `<T extends ChildLine> List<T>` and changing `List<Line>` to `<T extends Line> List<T>`. 

After erasure, both of these types should boil down to `List<T>`, which again means that they have the same signature and thus should override as expected. 

Regardless, I can cast the types as I need and proceed that way, just am asking these questions out of curiosity. Thanks for your help.

Comment: „*...so therefore `List<ChildLine>` is a `List<Line>`*“ — That's not how Java works. Look into [*covariance/contravariance*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_(computer_science)). — „*After erasure, both of these types should boil down to `List<T>`*“. That's not correct. There won't be any *`T`* after erasure. It is the *`T`* that's ***erased*** after all. — „*am asking these questions out of curiosity.*“ — Look into [*what the JLS says about type erasure*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.6). Read/ reread sections 8.4.2 + 8.4.8.1.